# Implement your own algorithm for resizing ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I know that the `ArrayList` has its own method for resizing the array when it reaches maximum size, but is there any way I can override that method and implement my own algorithm?

Comment: You can extend the class.

Comment: There is no such thing as array resizing ......

Comment: After extending the class, In case that method is declared as final or private we cannot override it.

Comment: Is this your college assignment?

Comment: Write your own ``List`` implementation, it's trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extend `ArrayList` and override `ensureCapacity(int)`. Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity%28int%29) for the javadoc and [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java) for the source code.

Comment: How do you propose to do this, given that `elementData` is private?

Comment: oops, didn't see that. Well I guess, if he really, really wanted to he could use reflection ;-)